# Rails: JQuery executing in console, not in js file

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing an app where users can post. I want to make it so that when a post's id is hashed in the url, the post flashes. To accomplish this, here is my code:

```
function getHash() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  return hash; 
}

if (getHash()) { 
    $(getHash()).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300);
}
```

Now, I know this code is run b/c if I put an `alert('in the if statement');`, it works whenever there is a hash in the url. I also know this part works:

```
    $(getHash()).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300);
```

because if I run it in the console, the post flashes. What is going wrong that is not allowing this to work?

Comment: put your getHash function in document ready ($(document).ready())

Comment: this is not the problem since the getHash() function executes just fine in the `if (getHash()) { ` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try your code like this

```
function getHash() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  return hash; 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  if (getHash()) { 
    $(getHash()).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300);
  }
})
```

I think since your element does not exist when your script is executing. Document ready works when whole document is prepared, and all your elements are in the place. Since everything seems fine, I think this will work

Thanks